# why some events do not work in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the events hash, i want to use resize event, but they
do not work neither. However, click event works well. why resize does not work?

```
var SubheaderView = Backbone.View.extend({

    id: 'gallery',
    tagName: 'div',

    events: {
        'click #minor': 'getPadding',
        'resize #minor': 'getPadding' //not work
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(subheaderTemplate);
    },

    getPadding: function() {
        var pad_top = Math.floor($('#minor').height() * 0.4);
        var pad_left = Math.floor($('#minor').width() * 0.07);
        var pad = pad_top + 'px 0px 0px ' + pad_left + 'px';

        $('#cover h1').css({'padding': pad});
    }
});
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879505/window-resize-event-for-backbone-view

Answer (score 2):

It does not related to `Backbone` at all. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize), only `window` has a `resize` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: 
Add this code to backbone.js file you are using

```
Backbone.View.prototype.eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
  $(window).resize(function () {
  Backbone.View.prototype.eventAggregator.trigger('window:resize');
});
```

Then bind the event aggregator to any view to want to use the resize event

```
this.eventAggregator.bind('window:resize',this.resize)
```

where `this.resize` is the function to be called for the resize event