# scrollable for <td> tag with only inline css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a system send an email via PHPMailer that will content 2 tables, one is freezed for the title and one is scrollable for the data. If the data is not too much then the scroll won't appear. i put the 2 tables inside a big table but the second table can't be scrolled no matter how i tried. Here is my structure:

```
<table>
<tr><td><table> ... </table></td>
<td><div style="overflow: auto"><table> .. </table></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

i tried to warp the second table with the  to make it scrollable but its not working so i think its best to post my problem here. Please help me 
P/s: I can only use inline css to compatible with all email clients

My expectation would be like this

[image]

Comment: not sure i do it right like you want, but have you try fixed size of the second table like this http://jsfiddle.net/jpgs59w8

Comment: @HenryVarro i added my expectation table image

Answer (score 1):

Well i guess something like this
You just need put fixed width for first div and create one more div (you have permission to do that right?) with more height like this

```
<table>
<tr style="border:none">
    <td style="border: none;">
        <table class="table" style="margin-top:-15px">
            <tr><td>Header1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="overflow: auto; width:300px">
            <div style="width:450px">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Header2</td>
                        <td>Header3</td>
                        <td>Header4</td>
                        <td>Header5</td>
                        <td>Header6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

A full demo you can see here [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jpgs59w8/1/) (just demo, you will need measure the width of both divs yourself to fit your website)

Comment: the problem is that when i resize the browser window, the scroll bar's width doesn't change. I need it responsively

Comment: because we fix the width of the div contain scrollbar, it can be responsively if you have access to css file by using @media like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550541/media-min-width-max-width)

Comment: can i use it in inline CSS? What i am doing only allow CSS inline :\