# media screen does not change font-size CSS

Tags: css

So I have some problem, if browser is full screen everything display correct, and when I change the size of browser my #table112 does not change it font-size, but it should change it according to logic. So where did I make mistake

```
#table112 {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 14px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both `min-width` and `max-width` in intermediate values to apply styles based on field widths when using a media query. Only `min-width` is used for the largest screen width and `max-widht` is used for the smallest screen width.

```css
#table112 {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 75px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    #table112 {
        font-size: 75px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="table112">TEST</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `min-width` and `max-width`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    #table112 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

To understand how these properties work in `@media`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550541/media-min-width-max-width).