# Apply same specific style to different media query

Tags: css

I wrote a specific style for min-width:769px and max-width:899px in media query, but I want to this same specific style to this range min-width:401px and max-width:768px how to do this?

I want to change width of the element at screen size of @media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:899px), even this width have to apply @media (min-width:401px) and (max-width:768px), but the condition is don't want to change min-width and max-width pixels, how can implement this?

Comment: I think this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550541/media-min-width-max-width

Comment: Just before, I inspected this, It could'nt help for me. But thanks for your response and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 media queries in hand.

1. @media(min-width:769px) and (max-width:899px){.class_name{}}
2. @media(min-width:401px) and (max-width:768px){.class_name{}}

We can combine both these scenarios as like below
@media(min-width:401px) and (max-width:899px){.class_name{ width: your_value}}